Issue with Safe CLI version
We have replayed our SAFE address as we had funds on BSC and the SAFE was for ETH. We are having issues with the Safe CLI version.
I encountered an error while using safe-cli. The command I ran was:
safe-cli 0x0e69A01180783d02DA5D9f497923CC44b527E2e6 https://bsc-mainnet.infura.io/v3/(My Key here)
We encountered this error
│   199 │   │   # Validate the version and parse it into pieces                                    │                                                                                                                                         │ > 200 │   │   match = self._regex.search(version)                                                │
self = <repr-error "'Version' object has no attribute '_version'"> │                        │
│ │ version = None
Addionally we also had this error
self = <repr-error "'Version' object has no attribute '_version'">
version = None
Is anyone please able to help

Could you please share the proper traceback formatted? I cannot follow the error you are sharing
